# Fail to interpolate the environment variable to ports declaration in "docker-compose.yaml"

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

### docker-compose.yaml

```yaml
version: "3"

services:

  Database:

    image: postgres
    container_name: Database
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "${DATA_BASE_PORT}:${DATA_BASE_PORT}"

    env_file:
      - 01-Source/Infrastructure/Interactions/ClientAndFrontServer/.env.dataBase.local.public
      - 01-Source/Infrastructure/Interactions/ClientAndFrontServer/.env.dataBase.local.private

    // ...
```

I made sure that paths to files are correct. If to make mistake in these path, the error like

```
open D:\IntelliJ IDEA\XXX\01-Source\Infrastructure\Interactions\ClientAndFrontServe
r\.env.dataBase.local.publicd: 
The system cannot find the file specified.
`docker-compose` process finished with exit code 14
```

will occur.

### .env.dataBase.local.public

```
DATA_BASE_HOST=localhost
DATA_BASE_PORT=5432
```

### The error

```
Ttime="2022-10-23T10:51:41+09:00" level=warning msg="The \"v\" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank st
ring."
1 error(s) decoding:

* error decoding 'Ports': No port specified: :<empty>
`docker-compose` process finished with exit code 15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `env_file` directive sets up environment variables *inside* the container and doesn't affect docker compose.

To set environment variables you can use in docker compose, you can either name the file `.env` or you can use the `--env-file` option on your docker compose commands

To use your database file, you'd do

```
docker-compose --env-file .env.dataBase.local.public up
```

More info here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#using-the---env-file--option

Answer (score 0):

### Solution for IntelliJ IDEA IDEs family

In the Docker setup at **Run/Debug Configurations**, specify the **Environment variables file** via **Modify options**:

[image]

What a pity that GUI available only in local development mode xD